# I am being attacked by a DDoS tool. How do I defend against it?

Tags: ddos

I used Cloudflare's waf and created several rules to allow only a few countries to access, deny access to old browsers, and started hosting rules. Although the defense was successful, my website was also. Therefore, the response is very slow. Ddos takes up a lot of the IP speed assigned to me by Cloudflare. How should I optimize it to prevent attacks?

Comment: For a large, distributed DOS attack, one of the few defenses is to increase your bandwidth. Filtering works until the attacker finds what you are filtering and evade it.

Comment: Optimise Cloudflare? What exactly do you want? This is missing some details. Is the DDoS hitting your Cloudflare WAF or your site? Are the DDoS rules working? How are you expecting to optimise something?